# Approximating cox model with time varying covariates using poisson

Tags: survival, python, cox-model, poisson-regression, statsmodels

How do you reformat a dataset in order to perform a cox regression with time-varying covariates as a poisson regression.

I'm trying to run a survival analysis regression in python with time varying covariates. Since this functionality is still pending, I thought I'd try to exploit the link between poisson and cox. I know how to reformat the dataset in order to get identical results in the non time varying covariate case: add new observations to each individual corresponding to each death time in the dataset.

How does the following dataset need to be split? Age is a time varying covariate and event is a dummy for death occuring:

```
id   start   stop   event   age
 1     0      3       0      30
 1     3      5       0      33
 1     5      6       1      35
 2     0      4       1      20
```

As an example, the non-time varying covariate case looks as follows:

```
 id   start   stop   event    x
 1     0       1       1      0
 2     0       2       1      1
 3     0       3       1      0
```

The split dataset looks as follows:

```
id   start   stop   event     x   riskset
 1     0       1       1      0     0
 2     0       1       0      1     0
 3     0       1       0      0     0
 2     1       2       1      1     1
 3     1       2       0      0     1
 3     2       3       1      0     2
```

`PHReg.from_formula("stop ~ x - 1",  df, status=df['event'], ties="efron")`

Gives the same results as

`Poisson.from_formula("event ~ x + C(riskset) - 1", df2)`

Comment: Which python package are you using, lifelines?